# Change <select> after reading <span> JS

Tags: javascript, html, select, css-selectors

So, I have a form with input and select. What I need to do is put another color in the camps that are required, and I'm trying not to change the html that I already have so I'm doing a function in JS.
For the input is easy cause I do the following function and it changes the color of the input cause the "data-val-required" is in the input.

```
  $('input').each(function () {
        var req = $(this).attr('data-val-required');
        if (undefined != req) {
            $(this).css("background-color", 'rgb(250, 255, 189)');
            $(this).attr('title', 'Este campo é obrigatório!');
        }
    });
```

But, for the select I can't do the same cause the "data-val-required" is in a span after the **`<select>`** . what I want to do is read the **`<span>`** and then color the **`<select>`** before it.

The html is something like this (the class="col-md-9" is the same for every camps of the form in the view)

```
<div class="col-md-9">
  <select class="form-control">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">TEXTO 1</option>
    <option value="2">TEXTO 2</option>
    <option value="3">TEXTO 3</option>
  </select>
  <span class="field-validation-error" data-val-required="true">Campo obrigatório</span>
</div>
```

I  tried this but this colors all the **`<select>`** camps I have in my code and not just only the ones required.

```
$('span').each(function () {
        var rep = $(this).attr('data-val-required');
        if (undefined != rep) {
            $('select').css("background-color", 'rgb(250, 255, 189)');
            $('select').attr('title', 'Este campo é obrigatório!');
        }
    });
```

Is there anyway without changing HTML, to make the function read the span and change just the select before that span?
I'm searching childNodes but I can't seem to do that with class instead of id.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had to select on direct child `'~'` ot type SPAN from SELECT with class form-control. For searching the SELECT look for a sibling from your SPAN with the desired class and type of SELECT.

```js
$('select.form-control ~ span').each(function () {
        var rep = $(this).attr('data-val-required');
        if (undefined != rep) {
            let select = $(this).siblings('select.form-control');
            select.css("background-color", 'rgb(250, 255, 189)');
            select.attr('title', 'Este campo é obrigatório!');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-9">
  <select class="form-control">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">TEXTO 1</option>
    <option value="2">TEXTO 2</option>
    <option value="3">TEXTO 3</option>
  </select>
  <span class="field-validation-error" data-val-required="true">Campo obrigatório</span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
  <select class="form-control">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">TEXTO 1</option>
    <option value="2">TEXTO 2</option>
    <option value="3">TEXTO 3</option>
  </select>
  <span>Campo obrigatório2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! 
This nodes where killing me, thank you!

Comment: Just look that you restrict your selectors as much as you can by using tags, classnames and ids. If you have a direct child use > and for a sibling  ~.

Comment: Ok thank you so much. I will use it to try go to another level. Instead of coloring (I did that cause it was easier), I will try to go to the label before and add an * .

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$('span').each(function() {
  var rep = $(this).attr('data-val-required');
  if (undefined != rep) {
   $(this).siblings('select').css("background-color", 'rgb(250, 255, 189)');
    $(this).siblings('select').find('select').attr('title', 'Este campo é obrigatório!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-9">
  <select class="form-control">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">TEXTO 1</option>
    <option value="2">TEXTO 2</option>
    <option value="3">TEXTO 3</option>
  </select>
  <span class="field-validation-error" data-val-required="true">Campo obrigatório</span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
  <select class="form-control">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">TEXTO 1</option>
    <option value="2">TEXTO 2</option>
    <option value="3">TEXTO 3</option>
  </select>
  <span>Campo obrigatório2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Better using sibling instead of parent and find because it's faster and the select could be much more deeper in your DOM-structure.

Comment: Sure thanks @Sascha. But you have copied by answer presentation. :-)